# R Shiny Leaflet Change Labels Without Redrawing

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I've been trying to change/update the popup labels based on user input. However, the map is redrawn everytime a change is made. I tried adding a delay without success. This might be a trivial question but I've been unable to solve it.

I'm using a SpaitalPolygonsDataFrame for the base data.

If I don't clearShapes(), the fillColor overwrites itself making the fillColor darker with each successive input. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(world_spdf) %>%
      addTiles()  %>%
      setView( lat=12.97, lng=77.59 , zoom=3) %>%
      addPolygons( fillColor = Data1$Color_Code, stroke=F, fillOpacity = 0.25)
  })

  observe({
    leafletProxy("map",data = world_spdf) %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(fillColor = Data1$Color_Code, stroke=F, fillOpacity = 0.25, popup = filteredData1(), smoothFactor = 0.2)
  })
```

Comment: Going to need the code of the whole app to debug that I think.

Comment: Have you looked into leafletproxy yet? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet/versions/2.0.1/topics/leafletProxy? Add a session variable to your server function and then use sthg like `leafletProxy("map", session) %>%
     clearShapes() %>%
      addPolygons(...)`,...

Comment: could that work for you?